# The coordinate of the data in osm point is too large

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap

I am working on postgresql for several days

I imported the data from open street map (osm)

everything works well until I translate the geometry type

the value it gives is very large. I have no idea what it is

[image: img for the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates are in the Web Mercator projection (3857) not in lat-long (4326). This projection uses meters from a reference point (lat-long 0;0)

Some tools such as `osm2pgsql` will use the Web Mercator by [default](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md#projection-options).